# JavaFX: ScatterPlots take too long to load

Tags: java, javafx, real-time, freeze, scatter-plot

I have a JavaFX GUI application that has 6 ScatterPlot graphs.  My application is reading & plotting data from a serial port.  The TextAreas are displaying the raw data with no problem.  My only issue is that when the application plots the points, the application freezes.  Can someone explain to me what is causing this issue?  Is there any way to fix it?  Is there any way of plotting the streaming data without making the application freeze?

I'd upload my code, but it's too long & exceeds the StackOverflow's limit of 3000 characters.

PS:  Most of my code is located in the start().

Comment: You'll need to upload code to get concrete assistance.  Create the smallest possible application you can which replicates the issue (and somebody could use standalone without some special serial port config) and edit your question to include that code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out!

Turns out the reason why my graphs were freezing was because all incoming data was running on 1 thread.  Using multiple threads improved the performance of the GUI & prevented the GUI from freezing